# Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, footer

I need create a **`cascading DropDownList`** in ASP.Net c# that is DropDownList which depend on the first DropDownList for the data in the **`Footer Template`** in my **`GridView`**.

When select a value from the first DropDownList I need populate the second DropDownList with the value of query sql3 execute in event **`First_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged`.**

In *debug* the output value selected in first DropDownList and the query sql3 are correct.

I've tried using this solution without success, because the error is:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: 
The name 'dtSubCategories' does not exist in the current context
```

In this line of code-behind:

```
Line 360:
Second_DDL.DataSource = dtSubCategories();
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Here is my code:

```
protected void First_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList First_DDL = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)First_DDL.NamingContainer;

    Response.Write(First_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 3) + "<br /><br />");

    sql3 = " SELECT FROM `tbl_m` WHERE fiedl1 = ?; ";

    Response.Write(sql3);

    DataTable dtSubCategories = new DataTable();

    using (OdbcConnection myConnectionString =
       new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        myConnectionString.Open();
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql3, myConnectionString))
        {
            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", First_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 3));
            adapter.Fill(dtSubCategories);
        }
    }
}


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        DropDownList Second_DDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Second_DDL");
        Second_DDL.DataTextField = "text";
        Second_DDL.DataValueField = "text";
        Second_DDL.DataSource = dtSubCategories();
        Second_DDL.DataBind();

    }
}
```

**EDIT #1**

```
DataTable dtSubCategories = new DataTable();


protected void First_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList First_DDL = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)First_DDL.NamingContainer;

    Response.Write(First_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 3) + "<br /><br />");

    sql3 = " SELECT FROM `tbl_m` WHERE fiedl1 = ?; ";

    Response.Write(sql3);

    DataTable dtSubCategories = new DataTable();

    using (OdbcConnection myConnectionString =
       new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        myConnectionString.Open();
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql3, myConnectionString))
        {
            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", First_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 3));
            adapter.Fill(dtSubCategories);
        }
    }
}


    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            DropDownList Second_DDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Second_DDL");
            Second_DDL.DataTextField = "text";
            Second_DDL.DataValueField = "text";
            Second_DDL.DataSource = dtSubCategories();
            Second_DDL.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

**EDIT #2**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Level_Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    OdbcConnection cn =
       new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);

    DataSet dset;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtCategories = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtSubCategories = new DataTable();
    OdbcDataAdapter dadapter;

    private DataTable RetrieveSubCategories(string TRZ)
    {
        string sql3 = " SELECT ... where TRZ = ?; ";

        using (OdbcConnection cn =
            new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql3, cn))
            {
                dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                dadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(?, TRZ.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 3));
                dadapter.Fill(dtSubCategories);
            }
        }
        return dtSubCategories;
    }

    private DataTable RetrieveCategories()
    {
        string sql2 = " SELECT ... ; ";

        using (OdbcConnection cn =
           new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql2, cn))
            {
                dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                dadapter.Fill(dtCategories);
            }
        }
        return dtCategories;
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            DropDownList First_DDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("First_DDL");
            First_DDL.DataTextField = "First_DDL";
            First_DDL.DataValueField = "First_DDL";
            First_DDL.DataSource = RetrieveCategories();
            First_DDL.DataBind();

            DropDownList Second_DDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Second_DDL");
            Second_DDL.DataTextField = "Second_DDL";
            Second_DDL.DataValueField = "Second_DDL";
            Second_DDL.DataSource = dtSubCategories;
            Second_DDL.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void First_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList TRZ = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)TRZ.NamingContainer;
        RetrieveSubCategories(TRZ.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 3));

        Response.Write(TRZ.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 3));
    }

    public DataTable GridViewBind()
    {
        using (OdbcConnection cn =
            new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sql1 = " SELECT ... ; ";

            using (OdbcDataAdapter command =
                new OdbcDataAdapter(sql1, cn))
            {
                cn.Open();
                dset = new DataSet();
                dset.Clear();
                command.Fill(dset);
                DataTable dt = dset.Tables[0];
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GridViewBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dtSubCategories  is local to First_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: thank you I have the same error, see EDIT #1 in question please.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your data table globally. Outside First_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged() function.Like this

```
DataTable dtSubCategories = new DataTable();
protected void First_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{..}
```

> Your problem is that the datatable is local to only first dropdown
>   list.

Comment: thank you I have the same error, see EDIT #1 in question please.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon Yogi's answer and Rex's comment, you're also calling `dtSubCategories` like a method when it is a variable. Either drop the parentheses or create a method/property to retrieve the data table.

```cs
//using the global variable
Second_DDL.DataSource = dtSubCategories;

//using a property
Second_DDL.DataSource = DTSubCategories;
public DataTable DTSubCategories
{
    get { return dtSubCategories; }
    set { dtSubCategories = value; }
}

//using a method
Second_DDL.DataSource = GetSubCategories();
private DataTable GetSubCategories()
{
    return dtSubCategories;
}
```

Comment: thank you, in **EDIT #2** of question my code-behind complete, I don't have error but the Second_DDL is always empty even when you select the value in First_DDL